# Getting some error after going to checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Getting a error while entering the checkout page, attached below is the screenshot.

[image]

Below is the code inside the file.

```
<?php
$mobileHelper = $this->helper('Meetanshi\Mobilelogin\Helper\Data');
if ($helper->isMobileloginEnabled()) {

if (!$mobileHelper->customerLoggedIn()) { ?>
    <div class="check-loginlink">
        <button class="action action-auth-toggle"
                id="checkoutlogin"><?php echo __('Already Have an Account? Click here to login') ?>
        </button>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.authentication-wrapper').hide();
            $('#checkoutlogin').on('click', function () {
                $('.mobile-sendotp-popup').modal('openModal');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .authentication-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }

    .check-loginlink {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
```

I had tried re-installing the plugin, but its still the same. Please if anyone can help me out that would be great.

Comment: Can you post the `checkoutlogin.phtml` content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 3, Replace

```
 if ($helper->isMobileloginEnabled()) {
```

with

```
if ($mobileHelper->isMobileloginEnabled()) {
```

Comment: It worked, thanks you very much